# How to get the value of last row and assign it to text box in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have created a list screen which searches the records based on some search criteria. The index of the list is employee_id. I want to add next and previous button in my list screen, for that I need to pass the employee_id of the last record from the list, so that next time for the same search criteria, I can get the next page which will fetch the employee details where employee_id is greater than the previous page last employee_id.

```
<table> 
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeList | orderBy:'emp_id'">
        <td>{{emp.emp_id}}</td>
        <td >{{emp.name}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.role}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.insertTime}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" name="lastempId" ng-value="emp.emp_id"/>
```

I want the last `emp_id` from the table in input tag `name="lastempId"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EmployeeList` itself to get the value of the last `emp_id`

```html
<input type="text" name="lastempId" ng-value="EmployeeList[EmployeeList.length - 1].emp_id" />
```

Comment: Thank you nash11, 
By using your suggested code i am able to get the value in text box.
But to send to the server, it is required to add ng-model tag.
When i add ng-model the data is not getting populated.
<input type="text" ng-model="lastempId" name="lastempId" ng-value="EmployeeList[EmployeeList.length - 1].emp_id" />

Comment: Thanks for giving me suggestion. I have used below code and it works.
<input type="text" name="lastempId" ng-init="lastempId=0" ng-value="lastempId=EmployeeList[EmployeeList.length - 1].emp_id"/>

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `EmployeeList` and get the last element through indexing. That is `EmployeeList[EmployeeList.length - 1]` should get the last employee.

If you are looping using the `ng-repeat` use may use the `ng-if="$last"` condition to check if the row is the last row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response.
I have added below code as per your suggestion.
<input ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeList" type="text"  ng-model="emp.emp_id" ng-if="$last"/>
 <h1>{{emp.emp_id}}</h1>
but i am not able to access the value inside <h1> tag ( i.e.    <h1>{{emp.emp_id}}</h1>).
This value is blank.

Comment: Thanks for giving me suggestion. I have used below code and it works.
<input type="text" name="lastempId" ng-init="lastempId=0" ng-value="lastempId=EmployeeList[EmployeeList.length - 1].emp_id"/>